# Gradle task to increment version number

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I need help with this task of Gradle which I am writing to increment version number of by webapp each time I build-

```
task incrementVersion (dependsOn: build) {
    Properties props = new Properties() 
    File propsFile = new File('gradle.properties') 
    props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream()) 
    Integer nextbuildnum = ( ((props.getProperty('artifactBuildNumber')) as BigDecimal) + 1 ) 
    props.setProperty('artifactBuildNumber', nextbuildnum.toString()) 
    props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null) 
    props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
    ant.replaceregexp(match:'String\\s+appVersion=\\s+&quot;.*&quot;;', replace:'String appVersion= &quot;'+nextbuildnum+'&quot;;', byline:true) {
        file 'src/main/webapp/index.jsp'
    }
}
```

**The task is running correctly without any error, artifactBuildNumber in gradle.properties is also increments correctly, however version number in my jsp page is not getting incremented.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: This issue must be located in the regexp

Comment: You should also do all this in a doLast {} block, otherwise it's being done every time you start gradle, whatever the task you execute.

Comment: @ToYonos: This is the string I am trying to replace- String appVersion = "45". May you suggest correction in regex?

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thanks for pointing this out, I am new to gradle, I went and read the documentation after your comment and learnt task lifecycle. It indeed solved my following problem, I invite you to answer the question and I will give right mark to it- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701309/gradle-task-for-local-tomcat-deployment

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp seems wrong, you miss a space after `appVersion` and i am not sure with the extra `;` at the end, try this :

```
ant.replaceregexp(match:'String\\s+appVersion\\s+=\\s+&quot;.*&quot;', replace:'String appVersion= &quot;'+nextbuildnum+'&quot;', byline:true) {
```

Comment: You have pointed it right, but I am sorry my appversion string is String appVersion= "45"; My mistake I have provided wrong string in previously. This is some other problem...